# Java - How to Validate Numerical User Input Within A Certain Range Correctly

Tags: java, if-statement

Just looking for a little help! I am working on a weight conversion program at the moment. I have it working correctly but now I'm trying to make it fool proof, i.e. if a user inputs a numerical value either below or over a certain range (in this case I'm looking for KG between the range of 0 and 450) a message will appear advising of the mistake and will then prompt the user to input their value again. I can do that with the following code but the problem is when the user inputs a valid value it will print the conversion of not only the valid input but also the previous incorrect value. I have attached a screenshot of Command Prompt demonstrationg the issue. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

```
public void kgToStonesAndPounds()
    {
    double kg = 0;
        
        
        System.out.println("Please enter weight in KG here, range must be between 1 and 450: ");
        kg = input.nextDouble();
        
        
        if ( kg >= 1 && kg <= 450 ) // validate kg
         System.out.printf("\nThe weight you have entered is %.0f KG\n" , kg);
        else
        {System.out.println( "Weight in KG must be in the range of 1 - 450" );
        this.kgToStonesAndPounds();
        }
      
      
        double pounds = kg * 2.204622;

        double stonesWithDecimal = pounds / 14;

        int stone = (int) stonesWithDecimal; // cast int to get rid of the decimal
        
        long poundsWithoutStone = (long)((stonesWithDecimal - stone) * 14); // Take the fractional remainder and multiply by 14
        
        System.out.println("This converts to " + stone + " Stone " + poundsWithoutStone + " Pounds " );
    }//end method kgToStonesAndPounds
```

[EXAMPLE IN COMMAND PROMPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYvvN.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `return` after you call the method again in the invalid case. That way when returning from the method call if it was called from this method it won't move out of else statement and execute the following code.

```java
public void kgToStonesAndPounds() {
    ...

    if ( kg >= 1 && kg <= 450 ) // validate kg
        System.out.printf("\nThe weight you have entered is %.0f KG\n" , kg);
    else {
        System.out.println( "Weight in KG must be in the range of 1 - 450");
        this.kgToStonesAndPounds();
        return; // here
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Java - How to Validate Numerical User Input Within A Certain Range Correctly

As long as you get the desired effect/result (sans bad side effects), one way is no more `correct` than another.

Here is how I might do it. Just prompt initially and then repeat the prompt if the input isn't correct.

```
double kg;
String prompt = "Please enter weight in KG here, range must be between 1 and 450: ";
System.out.println(prompt);
while ((kg = input.nextDouble()) < 1 || kg > 450) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
}
System.out.printf("\nThe weight you have entered is %.0f KG\n" , kg);
// now do something with kg
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion (call a method inside itself) isn't a way to handle errors, it should only be used when the logic requires it.

To ask again, use a loop that will exits only when the input is valid

```
double kg;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter weight in KG here, range must be between 1 and 450: ");
    kg = input.nextDouble();
    if (kg >= 1 && kg <= 450) {
        System.out.printf("\nThe weight you have entered is %.0f KG\n", kg);
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Weight in KG must be in the range of 1 - 450");
    }
} while (true);
```

And you can use modulo to simplify your code

```
double pounds = kg * 2.204622;
int stone = (int) pounds / 14;
int poundsWithoutStone = (int) pounds % 14;
System.out.println("This converts to " + stone + " Stone " + poundsWithoutStone + " Pounds ");
```

Comment: I agree with the point you are making and the answer you are giving, but this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71989579/14334528) solves the problem and answers the initial question 'Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?' when you reconstruct the problem and then solve it. Same goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71989662/14334528) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both Ausgefuchster and azro' answer work, I give my answer as additional one for discuss.
I think most of your code works fine, but you should struct your code more clearly. For the if statement and else statement has no common code to execute, thus all code in the method should be seperate into different branches. Like the following:

```
public void kgToStonesAndPounds()
    {
    double kg = 0;
        
        
        System.out.println("Please enter weight in KG here, range must be between 1 and 450: ");
        kg = input.nextDouble();
        
        
        if ( kg >= 1 && kg <= 450 ){ // validate kg
         System.out.printf("\nThe weight you have entered is %.0f KG\n" , kg);

      
        double pounds = kg * 2.204622;

        double stonesWithDecimal = pounds / 14;

        int stone = (int) stonesWithDecimal; // cast int to get rid of the decimal
        
        long poundsWithoutStone = (long)((stonesWithDecimal - stone) * 14); // Take the fractional remainder and multiply by 14
        
        System.out.println("This converts to " + stone + " Stone " + poundsWithoutStone + " Pounds " );
        }
        else
        {System.out.println( "Weight in KG must be in the range of 1 - 450" );
        this.kgToStonesAndPounds();
        }
      
    }//end method kgToStonesAndPounds
```

The reason that led to this problem is that after recursive execution of kgToStonesAndPounds  completes, the code will continue to run the rest codes which follow the else block.